# How to fix 'the virtualbox DHCP server has not assigned an ip address to the virtual device'

Tags: virtualbox

I can't start virtual device in Gennymotion or VirtualBox.

This is for a config VirtualBox, enable DHCP server address 192.168.56.100, subnetmark 255.255.255.0, lower address bound 192.168.56.101, upper address bound 192.168.56.254. adapter ipv4: 192.168.56.15

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, misleading me to think about virtual networking.
Oracle VirtualBox virtualization won't work alongside with Microsoft's Hyper-V features. Remove Hyper-V features from Windows Features, reboot your machine and try again.

Source: https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#run-genymotion-windows-hyperv